# Mixed content: Static resources use HTTP instead of HTTPS during WordPress installation

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, ssl

I have an https://www.example.com working with WordPress normally. All the assets are loaded correctly over HTTPS.

But that's not the same with https://sub.example.com (the SSL certificate includes this subdomain) and apparently, there's no issue with the certificate but all the assets are *redirected* to HTTP.

When I visit https://sub.example.com/wordpress/ to proceed with the setup, it redirects me correctly to https://sub.example.com/wordpress/wp-admin/setup-config.php but all the assets are loaded with HTTP, like:

```
http://sub.example.com/wordpress/wp-includes/css/buttons.min.css?ver=4.8.2
```

When it should be:

```
https://sub.example.com/wordpress/wp-includes/css/buttons.min.css?ver=4.8.2
```

I checked for `.htaccess` and also set `AllowOverride` to `None` for the entire folder (applied to the parent folders), so I think we can discard `.htaccess` redirects. Any ideas? This doesn't happen with the main domain (which is running on the same server).

My virtual hosts:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    # This is the one that works just fine
    <VirtualHost _default_:443>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName example.com

        DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com

        SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
        SSLHonorCipherOrder On
        SSLCipherSuite ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:ECDH+3DES:DH+3DES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:RSA+3DES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        SSLEngine on

        # Certificate Files Placeholders, but these are the files I set and all of them exist.
        SSLCertificateFile      /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile   /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
        SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl.crt/server-ca.crt
        SSLCACertificateFile    /etc/apache2/ssl.crt/ca-bundle.crt

        <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </FilesMatch>
        <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </Directory>

        BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
                nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
                downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
        BrowserMatch "MSIE [17-9]" ssl-unclean-shutdown
    </VirtualHost>

    # And this (and any other sudomain I add) behaves like the described above
    <VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName  sub.example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/sub/

        # It doesn't matter if I enable these or not, I get the same result.
        # SSLCertificateFile      /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
        # SSLCertificateKeyFile   /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
        # SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl.crt/server-ca.crt
        # SSLCACertificateFile    /etc/apache2/ssl.crt/ca-bundle.crt
    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

I set the `AllowOverride` directive in `apache2.conf` which other than that directive, remains the same as default.

The server is running Apache 2.4.10 in Debian 8.9

Comment: Is the a special need why use want to have the resource loaded vie https? After Installation the resources should be with https but I think this is not done during installation!

Comment: Even after the installation, all the resources are loaded via HTTP, even though is the Home URL and the Site URL are set to the HTTPS version. Mixed content everywhere, literally.

Comment: Have you checked whether the assets are hard coded to load over `http`?  If memory serves assets can be "enqueued" in WordPress and a lot of the time third-party theme and plugin developers set it to HTTP.

Comment: Yes, I'm using the https://wordpress.org/latest.zip version, it's clean without hard-coded URLs. This never happens normally, the WordPress installation assets URLs are automatically updated to match the current URL I think, or at least they use `//` to match it.

Comment: Can you share your Server config?

Comment: Sure, I updated the question.